# Get WMI Data From Multiple Computers and Export to CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, wmi

So having some good old fashion Powershell frustrations today.  What I need to do is this:

1. Get a list of computers from a file
2. Query those computers for "CSName" and "InstallDate" from Win32_OperatingSystem
3. Convert InstallDate into a useable date format.
4. Export all that to a .Csv

I've tried so many different iterations of my script.  I run into 2 major issues.  One is that I can't export and append to .Csv even with `Export-Csv -Append`.  It just takes the first value and does nothing with the rest.  The 2nd is that I can't get the datetime converter to work when piping `|`.

Here's a few samples of what I've tried - none of which work.

This sample simply errors a lot.  Doesn't seem to carry `$_` over from the WMI query in the pipe.  It looks like it is trying to use data from the first pipe, but I'm not sure.

```
    Get-Content -Path .\Computernames.txt | Foreach-Object {
        gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $_) |
            Select-Object $_.CSName, $_.ConvertToDateTime($OS.InstallDate).ToShortDateString()
    } | Export-Csv -Path Filename -Force -Append -NoTypeInformation
}
```

This one simply exports the first value and gives up on the rest when exporting .Csv

```
$Computers = Get-Content -Path .\Computernames.txt
foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {
  echo $Computer
  $OS = gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Computer
  $OS | Select-Object
  $OS.CSName,$OS.ConvertToDateTime($OS.InstallDate).ToShortDateString() |
      Export-Csv -Path $Log.FullName -Append
}
```

This one does get the data, but when I try to select anything, I get null values, but I can `echo` just fine.

```
$OS = gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Computers
$OS | Foreach-Object {
    Select-Object $_.CSName,$_.ConvertToDateTime($OS.InstallDate).ToShortDateString() |
        Export-Csv -Path $Log.FullName -Force -Append -NoTypeInformation
}
```

This feels like it should be ridiculously simple.  I can do this in C# with almost no effort, but I just can't get PS to do what I want.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go,

```
$Array = @() ## Create Array to hold the Data
$Computers = Get-Content -Path .\Computernames.txt

foreach ($Computer in $Computers)
{
    $Result = "" | Select CSName,InstallDate ## Create Object to hold the data
    $OS = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Computer

    $Result.CSName = $OS.CSName ## Add CSName to line1
    $Result.InstallDate = $OS.ConvertToDateTime($OS.InstallDate).ToShortDateString() ## Add InstallDate to line2
    $Array += $Result ## Add the data to the array
}

$Array = Export-Csv c:\file.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: It's a beautiful thing when something works!  I only made 1 slight change - the way the $Array was exporting it was only putting the length into the .csv so I just changed it to this:  $Array | Export-Csv -Path Results.csv and I got the full info returned.  Thank you so much for such a quick and complete answer!